# trackpad on laptop in Slackware 13.37 not very sensitive

Tags: mouse, slackware, touchpad

I was using Slackware 13.1 and working on my laptop with its trackpad and it was all Ok. When I installed 13.37 my trackpad became somewhat insensible. I have to push it harder than usual to make it move the mouse. How can this parameter be adjusted?

Comment: yeah... 1 mln. $ question

Answer (score 0):

If you are using KDE, a place to start might be `SystemSettings > Input Devices > Mouse > Advanced` and change the pointer acceleration.

If that doesn't help, try copying `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf` to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` and then editing the parameters. There might even be some parameters which are not in the default file.

Yours might not be a Synaptics device, but there may be more appropriate configuration files in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` that you can try.

You'll have to restart X before changes take effect.